#  I want to park my domain www.b.com to www.a.com. if the user visits b.com, I want the browser url to display a.com

Tags: domains, apache, redirects

I want to park my domain www.b.com to www.a.com

So far is working, but if the user visits b.com, I want the browser url to display a.com

Is there a way around it?

Comment: This seems like more of a server question than a programming question. In fact it's basically bog-standard DNS. Take a look at [this server fault question](http://serverfault.com/q/4604/35686). You just use a 301.

Comment: Is your website on Apache or IIS or something else?

Comment: Apache 2.2 version

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/24859/4033

Comment: @Sinan I think it's actually the opposite of that question - Pacerier wants to redirect the user from b.com to a.com, where as Sunny88 wants duplicate content on the two domains.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply forward b.com to a.com in your registrar account GoDaddy for example or where ever you registered the domain. This is better than doing it with any server side script. Another option is to create a CNAME record.

Comment: The problem with the CNAME approach is that it'll basically mirror the site at b.com instead of redirecting it. This could have negative SEO impact unless he sets a canonical URL. If he has access to redirect facilities, he should do that instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use mod_rewrite in your .htaccess file.

The Apache docs have a great example: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost

Drop this in your .htaccess file and all requests will be re-directed to www.a.com:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.a.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.a.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Also, don't forget `RewriteEngine On` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Possible a domain redirect using Domain B's name servers and A Records.

Or using Domain A's control panel to set up a redirect there

Comment: DNS Address Record

Comment: There's no way to do a redirect via DNS. Redirecting is done via HTTP (or JS or http-equiv meta tags). Also, there's no way to get b.com to redirect to a.com by only using a.com configurations. That would allow anyone to steal anyone else's domain.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear where you want the web content to come from. If the user visits `b.com`, you can set two things in action:

1. Effect a redirect to `a.com`, where the content is coming from the server at the other end of `a.com` and the URL is to match.
2. Mirror the content of the server at `a.com` under `b.com`, with that as the URL being accessed.

If you're serving data from a server at the other end of `b.com`, you should leave the URL as such. Cloaking it to read `a.com` is possible with some older browsers, but is a Bad Internet Practice™ for multitudes of security reasons.

It sounds like you'll be most successful with a domain redirect as [referenced in @Aeronaught's comment](https://serverfault.com/q/4604/35686).

Comment: i couldn't understand that answer at all.. where do i put the `<virtualHost>` tag?

Comment: @Pacerier That would be in the destination server's own configuration; assuming it's running Apache, that snippet would go in httpd.conf on the server. You need to provide more information on your hosting environment if that doesn't make sense.